# How can i call a Python function from a script that was meant to run on command line

Tags: python-2.7, argparse, mxnet

I would like to run this function from a script instead of the command line. For example, the function is:

```
def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Caffe prototxt to mxnet model parameter converter.\
                    Note that only basic functions are implemented. You are welcomed to contribute to this file.')
    parser.add_argument('caffe_prototxt', help='The prototxt file in Caffe format')
    parser.add_argument('caffe_model', help='The binary model parameter file in Caffe format')
    parser.add_argument('save_model_name', help='The name of the output model prefix')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    ...
```

How can i run it like this?

```
file.main('file_1.csv', 'file_2.csv', 'name')
```

And why would someone write a function that I can only run from the command line? It feels inconvenient.

Comment: This function is written because it's usually bad to write code under `if name == '__main__'`.

Comment: Hi @wRAR, do you have any references for me to read up why is it so? Thanks a lot.

Comment: It's simple, you can't call code written under `if name == '__main__'` as easily as code written in a separate function, when you need to call it from a different place.

Comment: ah. i mean why not just write a function with parameters. eg. def main(file1, file2, name):... @wRAR

Comment: You may want to call `main()` from different scripts etc. OTOH it is a very good idea to separate the actual code that works with parsed arguments to a separate function.

Comment: What does `main` do with `args`?  The part you showed us just parses the command line (something has to do that if it can be run as a script).  The real action follows.  Does it, for example, pass `args` (or its attributes) to another function?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `sys.argv`:

```
import sys

sys.argv.extend(['file_1.csv', 'file_2.csv', 'name'])
file.main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to do a little light re-factoring.  Pull the `argparse` stuff into its own method which then calls `main(args)`, and then instantiate your own `argparse.Namespace()` that you pass into `main` with your configuration.

And yes, I agree the code would be better if it was already factored this way.  But people code pragmatically to meet their immediate needs.